# BufferedWriter and map function: empty files

Tags: python, file, buffer, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write a huge output file the quickest possible on two different files.
I have created my lists list1 and list2, and I am now trying to write those in a respective file.

I started to increase the buffer size by doing so:

```
rand_file = io.FileIO("test1.txt", 'w')
    
writer = io.BufferedWriter(rand_file,buffer_size=500000000)
        
for x in mylist1:

    writer.write(x.encode())

writer.flush()

rand_file = io.FileIO("test2.txt", 'w')
    
writer = io.BufferedWriter(rand_file,buffer_size=500000000)

for x in mylist2:

    writer.write(x.encode())

writer.flush()
```

but now I wanted to change those "for loops" with list comprehension but I cannot make it work.

if I do the following:

```
writer.write(x for x in mylist1)
```

I do have the following error ***"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'generator'"***. Note I also tried `writer.write(x.encode() for x in mylist1)`, with the same result.

I then wanted to use the map function like so:

```
map(writer.write, mylist1)
```

This time, no error are raised but my output files are empty.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Your present code is fine, IMO. A list comprehension is used to create a list. `writer.write()` expects exactly one bytes like object. It makes no sense trying to put those two together.

Comment: Regarding the `map`: it only creates an iterator. If you do not iterate over it, there is no action.